# PowerBI: I have a table with Jira issues and their associated sprints. Some carried over to next sprint. How do I show 1st sprint issue was in?

Tags: powerbi, jira, powerbi-desktop

[image: Sprint Table with Issues]

Hello,

I am making a PowerBI dashboard to show sprint metrics. I am using the PowerBI Connector App for Jira. I have a table, (SprintIssues) that show the Sprint ID, Sprint Name, Issue ID, and Issue Key. Some issues were carried over to the next sprint, so, as you can see in the image with AGGEDI-125, the Issue Key is listed multiple times but in different sprints.

My ultimate goal is to count how many bug issues were **opened ** in each sprint. Simply doing a straight count will include issues that carried over.

How do I count only the issues that were opened in the sprint and exclude the ones that carried over?

Ulitimately, I want a widget like this:
[image: Ideal widget]

Does that make sense what I'm trying to do?

Thank you so so much in advance!

As aforementioned, I want to have a widget that shows the count of the bugs that were opened in each sprint. I want to exclude any bugs that were carried over.

Ulitimately, I want a widget like this:
[image: Ideal widget]

Comment: Opened in the sprint = ticket open date is between sprint start and end date. You just have to include that criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract sprint number from sprint name
[image]
Then group by key with min sprint number

[image]
Then populate sprint name column back
[image]

Then do the stacked bar chart
[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness! I think that worked! Thank you, @ashok Anumula!